# Can we deploy logic app individually present in the same resource group using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have a requirement to deploy a logic app individually which is present in different repositories. These logic apps are available in the same resource group. Can this be achieved using ARM template in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you seek is completely possible. Just have separate ARM templates for each of the Logic APP. You need to use the ARM template in the Incremental mode then, all your logic apps will be deployed individual and it will not clear out the old deployed resources in the resource group